# Detect if an Image Pixel's Column or Row is a Line

Tags: opencv, image-processing, line, ocr, noise

I'm trying to detect the border of the scanned documents because it will help increase my OCR extraction rate. Borders are considered marginal noise so I have to get rid of them. Borders usually have the highest density in an image.

I had examine every column of pixels in an image and the column which has the highest density is probably a border, if and only if, it is a line. And that's where my problem arises. I don't know how to detect if the column of pixel is a line or not.

Any help would be very much appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use Hough line transform, but it will give lines for the data on which you need to do OCR.

The simplest solution based on your question i can think of is this.
Since its border, you can reduce the search space based on some threshold in width and height.
For example, if your image is **'w x h'** and your search space width **'s'** your search space will be **'0 to s' 'w-s to w' '0 to s' 'h-s to h'**.

Comment: how will I get the value of s / search space?

Comment: it depends on the image. if you can edit the ques and put an image it will be helpful. if you border is more or less fixed for every image, you can hardcode a value for 's'.
And also if your borders are well connected you can remove the borders based on CCL labeling.

Answer (score 0):

There is in Opencv a line detection algorithm based on Hough transform :[Tutorial on Hough transform](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html)

This will detect the line existing in your image, you just have to see after if the pixel you detect as border belong to one of the detected lines.